# Screen in kivy refuses to update

Tags: python, kivy

i need to update my kivy screen with some widgets, with a thread.eveything in the thread works perfectly with the exception of the widgets to be updated on the screen

```
<ViewScreen>:
    id:grid
    pic:pic
    cols:2
    spinner:spinner

    MDSpinner:
        active:False

class ViewScreen(Screen):
    grid = ObjectProperty(None)
    pic = ObjectProperty(None)
    spinner = ObjectProperty(None)


    def load_real(self):
        _thread.start_new_thread(self.list_files, ('name',))

    def list_files(self, name):
        time.sleep(1)
        self.ids.spinner.active = True
        self.ids.grid.clear_widgets()
        url = 'http://po.com/{}'.format(str(self.code_url[0]))

        r = requests.get(url)
        data = r.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
        for link in soup.find_all('a'):
             if link.get('href').endswith('.png'):
                 print(link.get('href'))
                 self.passed.append(link.get('href'))
              print(self.passed)

             for photo in self.passed:
               src = 'http://po.com/{}/{}'.format(self.code_url[0],photo)
               print(src)
               album = AsyncImage(source=src, )
               self.ids.grid.add_widget(album)
               self.spinner.active = False
               self.code_url.pop(0)
               print(self.code_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Kivy is not thread safe. If you want to touch anything related to widgets, you have to call it from inside the kivy's loop. A thread should be used only for data collection.

So:

1. Collect data from an external source.
2. When done, use `Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: callback(data))` to refresh the GUI, where `callback` is a widget manipulation function, and `data` is the collected data to be displayed.